# C# reading binary file to struct (with sub-struct)

Tags: c#, struct, binary

I came from C/C++, so structuring binary in C/C++ is simply just casting a pointer to raw binary. However, what if I have something like this:

```
struct STRUCT {
  SUBSTRUCT a;
  ushort    b[3];
  int       c;
}

struct SUBSTRUCT {
  ushort   d[3];
}
```

with a binary file format of

```
AA AA AA AA AA AA BB BB BB BB BB BB CC CC CC CC
```

How do I convert this binary file to STRUCT in C#?

Comment: Are you open to _any_ method or are you hoping for a raw-data-copy solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the easiest and most straightforward way. You'll need to handle any byte order issues yourself:

```
class Struct
{

  public static Struct Rehydrate( BinaryReader reader )
  {
    Struct instance = new Struct() ;

    instance.a = SubStruct.Rehydrate( reader ) ;

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < instance.b.Length ; ++i )
    {
      instance.b[i] = reader.ReadUInt16() ;
    }

    instance.c = reader.ReadInt32() ;

    return instance ;

  }

  public void Dehydrate( BinaryWriter writer )
  {
    this.a.Dehydrate( writer ) ;

    foreach( ushort value in this.b )
    {
      writer.Write( value ) ;
    }

    writer.Write( this.c ) ;

    return ;
  }

  public SubStruct a = null ;
  public ushort[]  b = {0,0,0};
  public int       c = 0 ;

}
class SubStruct
{

  public static SubStruct Rehydrate( BinaryReader reader )
  {
    SubStruct instance = new SubStruct() ;

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < instance.d.Length ; ++i )
    {
      instance.d[i] = reader.ReadUInt16() ;
    }

    return instance ;
  }

  public void Dehydrate( BinaryWriter writer )
  {
    foreach( ushort value in this.d )
    {
      writer.Write(value) ;
    }
    return ;
  }

  public ushort[] d = {0,0,0} ;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could open this file and read it with a BinaryReader and use Marshal to cast it to Struct.
It's not a definitive answer, but should get you pointed in the right direction.

```
public static T ByteToType<T>(BinaryReader reader)
{
    byte[] bytes = reader.ReadBytes(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)));

    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    T theStructure = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
    handle.Free();

    return theStructure;
}
```

Comment: How do I tell C# about a fixed array size variables?

Comment: The file will need to be formatted exactly as the struct requires. It is blindly reading the specified number of bytes that the struct requires from the file and setting it. You may also need to define the struct layout a little more with StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit) and using the FieldOffset decorator.